# How to redirect onto other page with a passing function call along with it?

Tags: php

//here after session created i must redirect to 'home.php' along with a function call on the page 'home.php'

```
<?php
if($postname == $storedUsername && $postPassword == $storedPassword)
                { 
                    $_SESSION['authentication'] = 1;
                    header('location:home.php');  

?>
```

Comment: You cannot "pass a function call", since a function only makes sense within a script or process, but not within an http request. What you _can_ do is add some parameter to the script that is recognized by the requested script (`home.php`) and triggers a function call in there. So something like `header('Location: home.php?call=my_function');`

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do this.

**Method 1**

The simplest way would be using a GET parameter:

```
<?php
if($postname == $storedUsername && $postPassword == $storedPassword)
                { 
                    $_SESSION['authentication'] = 1;
                    header('Location: home.php?loadfunc=true');  
                    die();
                 }

?>
```

*Note: You did not close the brace above in your original code...not sure if this was intentional. You also did not invoke a `die` or `exit` function after your header redirection. This is dangerous to do as people will still be able to access the rest of your code if you do not want them to.*

Then in the home.php page do the following:

```
if (!empty($_GET['loadfunc'])){
    //call function here
}
```

*Note: Anyone can type a GET parameter into the address bar and anyone can read the address using a packet sniffer. If you do not want people to be able to do this, do not use this method.*

**Method 2**

A better way to do it might be to just check the SESSION variable on the home.php page:

```
session_start();
.... 
if (!empty($_SESSION['authentication']) && $_SESSION['authentication'] == 1){
     //call function here
}
```

I recommend this last method if it works for your code.
I

Comment: Can you explain what they are doing. They should both work.

Comment: Try displaying your variables at the top of the home.php script to see if they are filled correctly. For example, `print_r($_GET);` for method 1 above or `print_r($_SESSION);` for method 2.

Comment: First one just passing loadfunc as parameter

Comment: Then the if statement should work for the first one. Can you place an echo statement inside the if block to see if it is actually getting in that block. Ex. `echo "I am here";`

Comment: yes thats working... but what about the function?? its not calling

Comment: Then my code is working fine. Put an echo on the line before and another echo on the line after your function call. Also, put an echo inside of your function itself to see if it is being called. This will give you some indication as to what is going on.

Comment: Using echos at various places in your program help you to diagnose what is going on. Usually I number them such as `echo "Here #1";` and `echo "Here #2";` etc.

Comment: here 1  here 3  is the output actually  i placed an echo in functio that is here2 thats missing in output

Comment: Was "here2" the very first line inside of your function, or is it inside of an an if or loop structure?

Comment: Then it would seem you must not be making your function call correctly (or your function is defined incorrectly). Have you looked at your PHP logs to see what they say?

Comment: if (!empty($_GET['loadfunc'])){
  echo'here #1';
    function Viewall()
 {
  echo'im here';
 }
 echo'here #2';
}

Comment: That is creating a function, not calling a function.

Comment: thats wat im saying i have to call it directly from previous page

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear. :)

Comment: No, it would be best to ask as a new question anyhow.